# How do i make Boolean actually work?

Tags: modifiers

Did you know how much I despise Boolean?
im trying to make a desert eagle, and therefor im trying to make the barrel bisect through the front part of the gun. but here is what happens
[image]

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the fast solver?

Comment: Booleans don't like non-manifold geometry (that's a guess and a hint). Unfortunately neither your description nor your screenshot tell much about your mesh. Or the expected outcome. You can either provide more information or upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gBBQ4r6Z/) so we can take a look at it.